# Creando controles en formularios

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Estoy iniciandome en Java, estoy usando IntelliJ IDEA, creando una app de escritorio, me encuentro creando un formulario y agregandole controles, como `Label`, `TextBox`, `Button` y veo que todo se hace por código:

```
public class frmLogin extends JFrame {

    //Objetos del formulario
    private JLabel lblUsuario;
    private JLabel lblClave;
    private JLabel lblImagen;
    private JTextField txtUsuario;
    private JPasswordField txtClave;
    private JButton btnAceptar;
    private JButton btnCancelar;

    public frmLogin(){
        setTitle("Ingreso al Sistema");
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(390, 180);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Creamos objetos del formulario
        lblUsuario = new JLabel("Usuario:");
        txtUsuario = new JTextField(10);
        lblClave = new JLabel("Clave:");
        txtClave = new JPasswordField(10);
        btnAceptar = new JButton("Aceptar");
        btnCancelar = new JButton("Cancelar");

        //Adicionar objetos al formulario
        add(lblUsuario);
        add(txtUsuario);
        add(lblClave);
        add(txtClave);
        add(btnAceptar);
        add(btnCancelar);

        //Ubicamos objetos en el formulario
        lblUsuario.reshape  (20, 20, 100, 20);
        txtUsuario.reshape  (120, 20, 160, 20);

        lblClave.reshape  (20, 45, 100, 20);
        txtClave.reshape  (120, 45, 100, 20);

        btnAceptar.reshape  (20, 75, 90, 60);
        btnCancelar.reshape  (120, 75, 90, 60);
    }
}
```

¿Hay alguna forma de agregar un ToolBox por medio de un plugin que contenga los controles y formularios?

¿Oh es que todo se hace a código en Java?

Comment: Utiliza Swing ,En la pestaña “Project“, hacemos click derecho en “src” y luego en las opciones “New” -> “GUI Form“.

Comment: @Rastalovely excelente resulto.

Comment: @Rastalovely agregalo como respuesta para que pueda poner la pregunta como respondida.

Comment: @PedroÁvila si considera que te la respuesta ha sido de ayuda o ha respondido a su pregunta favor de marcarla como valida.

Comment: @Rastalovely Tu respuesta esta bien pero debes agregarle algún enlace, mejorarla un poco es un standar en SOes.

Comment: Ok en eso estoy....

Comment: Referencia ... https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/ide/intellij-gui-designer-example/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utiliza Swing

En la pestaña “Project“, hacemos click derecho en “src” y luego en las opciones “New” -> “GUI Form“.

Comment: pero elabora un poco la respuesta ;)